# FTP timeout only the first time

Tags: macos, ftp

I'm using PureFTPd on MacOSX (Snow Leopard, not server version). When trying to access the FTP account from the outside via dyndns (e.g. using https://www.wormly.com/test_ftp_server) the connection always **times out the FIRST time**. 
When I try **AGAIN in the next few seconds it works**.

What is this about?

I have forwarded the ports to my apple router and tried disabling the OSX firewall as well.

Thanks for any advice.

Dennis

Comment: This only happens when you test thru the website?

Comment: unfortunately not, no. I also tested FTP access from another computer, from my android phone and from the website above. The behaviour stays the same.

Comment: hmmm. that is strange.  Have you tried removing the router and conntecting directly to your Internet connection?

Comment: if you do not use the dyndns, will it work the first time? Using the ip address?